# Pricing for deploying multiple Azure Functions to the same App Service Plan (Elastic Premium Plan - EP1)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I'm planning to promote a set of Azure Functions (~15) to production. Today we're using for development purposes the Consumption plan but the cold start nature of this plan might impact the overall experience.

I've been searching for a best cost-benefit plan for deploying the application and found that the Elastic Plan EP1 would fit our needs (e.g. no cold start, rapid scale out, "... share an App Service Plan accross multiple funcion apps ...", etc).

The problem is that I didn't find precisely how this Plan would be charged...

In the scenario exposed, would I be charged 388.67 BRL for each of the approx. 15 functions deployed to the Plan? Or would the charge be for the Plan itself and the Functions would share the resources of the Plan?

And also, all the Function Apps on the Plan would be pre-warmed?

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Even not finding the answers clearly on the official documentation, I created the EP1 Plan and deployed the Functions.

1. I found that for a given App Service Plan (e.g. Elastic Plan EP1), I can deploy many Function Apps to it, but they share resources of that Plan, increasing the "[app density](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/05/21/App-Service-Plan-Density-Check.html)".
2. I still don't get the answer for the cold start question: for that Plan, if I deploy the 15 Function Apps to it would them be pre-warmed? I found that I can set "pre-warmed=1" in every Function App, but still experiencing cold starts.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question about the cost? I am on a similar state and want to ensure I am not paying for every function app with 1 pre-warmed instance on a single shared premium plan

Comment: Thanks for your edit GlauberMD - this helped massively knowing that the function apps SHARE resources within the plan.

The use of the word 'instance' is so vague in the documentation - it's not clear if they refer to the app service plan instance or the function app instance!

Answer (score 1):

No. If you dont set the pre-warmed instance, only one instance will be pre-warmed by default. You need to go the **Platform Features** tab to change the number of pre-warmed instances.

[image]

If you only care about the cost of the premium plan, you can use this calculator to get the cost:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=functions

And these is the documents about the premium plan:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#features

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan

Let me know whether this can answered your question.:)

Comment: The answer is not clear regarding the pre-warmed instances... For the 15 function apps I have, would I need to set "Pre-Warmed Instances"= 15 to avoid cold start for any of the 15 function apps?

Comment: Is there any place that states this clearly on the Azure documentation reference? I didn't find that and this leads to a misunderstanding regarding the costs of the solutions that rely on Azure Function Apps.

Comment: @GlauberMD I am very sorry for reply too late. I think this doc is what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#plan-and-sku-settings And you can use this calculator to estimate the cost of your function app. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ But you need to notice that if your minimum instance is more than pre-warmed instance, then you are pay for the mi nimum instance basiclly.

Comment: regarding your comment: " If you have 15 functions and dont want them to cold down, then you need to set "Pre-Warmed Instances"= 15", it seems to be incorrect. I created that scenario and one needs to set Pre-warmed = 1 in each Function App present on the given Application Plan. This setting is per function app.

Comment: @GlauberMD I am not sure your comment: "I created that scenario and one needs to set Pre-warmed = 1 in each Function App present on the given Application Plan. This setting is per function app." What do you mean about this? From your question seems one pre-warmed instances is not enough. So you need to set more pre-warmed instances. I know pre-warmed is a setting for per function app. But this doesn't matter, when you pay for it, you are based on minimum instances.

Comment: @GlauberMD Have a look of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#plan-and-sku-settings "You are charged for each instance allocated in the minimum instance count regardless if functions are executing or not."

Comment: on the question I say: “ I'm planning to promote a set of Azure Functions (~15) to production.”. The scenario is to deploy 15 different Function Apps to the same App Plan with 1 pre-warmed instance for each of them.